# $msqli->insert_id always returns '0' after a server move

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Until a server move this week (by the hosting provider) this code worked perfectly:

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','dbuser','dbpass','dbname');
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
$new_tester = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO testers (tid,first_name,last_name,t_email,company,last_login,ip_address) VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?,NULL,?)");
$new_tester->bind_param('sssss',$first_name,$last_name,$t_email,$up_company,$ip_address);
$new_tester->execute();
$userid = $conn->insert_id;
$new_tester->store_result();
$new_tester->close();
print($userid);
```

Since the move, insert_id always returns 0. I've moved the line with insert_id before/after store_result() and close(), and it still doesn't work.

For the record, it works as expected on my local machine. Both my machine and the server use PHP 5.6 and MySQL 5.0.11. AUTO_INCREMENT is in use.

Comment: Does it actually insert a new row in the table?

Comment: No, it does not. It used to, but no longer.

Comment: Well, then there is your issue. You can't get the ID of the last inserted row, if it does not insert anything. Add `echo $new_tester->error;` and `echo $conn->connect_error;` to your code, to make sure that you actually connect, and that the statements are executed properly. If not, they will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried that, but no error message occurs. I am connecting to the database at some level because I can retrieve data, but it won't write data. Hmm.

Comment: have you try to insert a data manually from a mysql console client? try it with the 'dbuser' and 'dbpass' that you're using to see if it's a grant priviledge problem

Comment: Ya, tried that using phpMyAdmin and it worked fine.

Comment: I'm very sure that those two would give you whatever issue you're facing. Take a look at [documentation for `$stmt->error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error.php). Also, all of these returns a resource on success, and a boolean *false* on failure, so wrapping each statement in a `if`-statement that echos out if it fails, can also give you an indicator on what's wrong.

Comment: Resolved! For some reason after the move, the database did not like NULL for the "last_login" field. The "last_login" field is a CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and was supposed to "ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP." It never threw an error, so it was difficult to find. **The solution was to change NULL to now().**